# How do I get specific fields on x axis and y axis on a chart for a report in salesforce?

Tags: report-chart

I want to have start date (grouped by calendar month) on the X axis but at the moment I only see record count which is frustrating :/

Can someone shed some light on this please ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a group-by filter for the axis you want to appear on the report. You can only include axis for fields that are grouped.